# How can I go, be redirected to another component by pressing the button in react, chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I create chrome extension in Rect. How can I go, be redirected to another component by pressing the button in react, chrome extension?

How can I go, be redirected from the `App` component (after pressing the button) to the `ItemDetails` component? Without using conditions (ternary operator).

I found such an article: [Routing in Chrome Extension written in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335424/routing-in-chrome-extension-written-in-react)

```
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'
const history = createMemoryHistory()

render() {
  let page = null
  switch (this.state.page) {
  case 'home':
    page = <Home />
    break
  case 'user':
    page = <User />
    break
  }
  return page
}
```

I do not understand this `this.state.page`. If I want to go to another component, how can I get this `this.state.page`. How do I save the component name in the state it wants to go to?

[Code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-be4lpn)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


class ItemDetails extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  render() {

    return (  
      <div>
        <p>
            Description:vvvvvvvvvvv
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      items: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello'
        }
      ],
      form: {}
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
         <form action="" method="post" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

            <button type="submit" value="Submit" >Log in</button>
          </form>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: When you say `redirected` is about changing current URL? or just mounting another component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Routes` to redirect to other component. You can make route like,

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path='/itemDetails' component={ItemDetails} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In component where you have button to redirect, you need to use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter).

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/itemDetails');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <button type="submit" >Log in</button>
          </form> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard)
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cvvtfc)

**Note:** Don't use `action="" method="post"` on form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-router-dom. First when you install router you need to import few things.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Than you need to setup different routes for pages for example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App>
    <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
    <Route path="/details" component={ItemDetails} />
  </App>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In your app component onSubmit function you can use history object to push user to the specific page:

```js
onSubmit = () => {
  this.props.history.push('/details');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a handler method `onSubmit`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      currentPage: "Page Name A",
      items: [
        {
          name: 'A',
          description: 'Hello'
        }
      ],
      form: {}
    };
  }

  onSubmit = (event) => {
    this.setState({ currentPage: "Page Name B" })
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.currentPage}
          <form action="" method="post" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
          </form>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-itkyhq?file=index.js

`onSubmit` does two things:

1. Set the name of the page to the state
2. Prevents the post request (react will handle the form)

Note: You can also remove `action` and `method` from `<form />` since it will not be used.

Learn more about [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), [`forms`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html?) and [handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#___gatsby) in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs).

Answer (score -1):

Use Router to redirect to another page or component...

this will route your path....

[For complete router options go to link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)